# Is $d(x,y)=\bigg[\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x_n-y_n)^2 \bigg]^{1/2}$ a metric on the set of all real sequences whose almost every term is zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

The question given in my book goes exactly as follows:

> Let $X$ consist of all sequences $x=\{x_n\}$ of all real sequences, such that all but finitely many terms $x_n$ are zero. Prove that $d(x,y)=\bigg[\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x_n-y_n)^2\bigg]^{1/2}$ is a metric on $X$.

**Approach:**

**Claim:** $X \subset l_1 \subset l_2$

**Proof:** By hypothesis, $\forall \ \mathbf{x}=\{x_n\} \in X$, $\exists   \ k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0, \quad \forall \quad n \geq k$. [only finitely many terms are $ \neq 0$]

So, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|=\sum_{n=1}^kx_n<\infty$. Which implies $\mathbf{x}\in l_1$.

The rest follows from the Minkowski's inequality, i.e. $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n+b_n|^2)^{1/2} \leq (\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^2)^{1/2}+(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^2)^{1/2}$

Is this the correct approach? Please verify.

Comment: Sounds fine to me...

Comment: Looks OK, but how does "All but finitely many ≡ Almost all"? On real line, "almost all" may not include countably many points, not just a finite set.

Comment: @dnqxt, I couldn't interpret it otherwise here. Should I correct it?

Comment: As you wish -- it's not a big deal anyway, I just find it unnecessary to re-declare "all but finitely many" given its clear meaning.

Comment: If you already know that it is a metric on $\mathbb R^n$ for some other reason (e.g. you're familiar with scalar products) then you can argue that all the metric axioms are "local" : they only refer to finitely many vectors, and therefore all the inequalities or equalities that you want can be checked in some $\mathbb R^n$, in which they are true